# Gradle config no longer works in Android Studio 3 (beta)

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio-3.0

My Android Studio project has a directory structure like this:

```
project
|-- build.gradle
|-- settings.gradle
|
|-- app
|    |-- src
|    |-- build.gradle
|    +-- settings.gradle
|
+-- submodule
     |-- build.gradle
     |-- settings.gradle
     +-- library
          |-- src
          |-- build.gradle
          +-- settings.gradle
```

`project/submodule` is a git submodule and refers directly to the git repository for another Android Studio project. Its `settings.gradle` is just `include ':library'`.

**Previously working config**

`project/settings.gradle` says `include ':submodule/library'`. `project/app/build.gradle` has the line `compile project(':submodule/library')`.

This all worked fine before Android Studio 3, but now Android Studio complains that it can't find modules by that name:

`Error:Unable to find module with Gradle path ':submodule/library' (needed by module 'Accession'.)`

(Running a build in the command line with gradle appears to work fine, so it seems to just be Android Studio that doesn't like something.)

Looking online it seems like referring to `:submodule/library` might only ever have worked by coincidence as the the name of the project as specified in the gradle config was assumed verbatim to be the same as the relative path of its root.

I have two possible solutions:

**Possible solution 1**

Replace `:submodule/library` with `:submodule:library` in both `build.gradle` and `settings.gradle`. This appears to work, but my best guess is that it includes the gradle project `:submodule` as well as its subproject. More to the point, I'm not really sure what this `:x:y` notation actually represents.

**Possible solution 2**

Replace `include ':submodule/library'` with

```
include ':library'
project(':library').projectDir = file('submodule/library')
```

in `settings.gradle` and replace `compile project(':submodule/library')` with `compile project(':library')` in `build.gradle`.

I suspect this might be the "right thing to do".

**Question**

Could somebody tell me what exactly is going on for each of these three bits of gradle (the original config and the two possible fixes), which (if any) should work and which is "best practice"?

**Update (Clarification)**

What I've described happens both with my old Gradle and Android Gradle Plugin version config (Gradle 3.3, Android Gradle Plugin 2.3.3) and after updating both (Gradle 4.1, Android Gradle Plugin 3.0.0 beta).

Answer (score 0):

They changed alot of things in the new gardle release, my build scripts also haven't worked anymore. But here is a good documentation about how to migrate your build-script to work with the newer version.

For example this part of the documentation should be sth for you:

You should instead configure your dependencies as follows:

```
dependencies {
// This is the old method and no longer works for local
// library modules:
// debugCompile project(path: ':foo', configuration: 'debug')
// releaseCompile project(path: ':foo', configuration: 'release')

// Instead, simply use the following to take advantage of
// variant-aware dependency resolution. You can learn more about
// the 'implementation' configuration in the section about
// new dependency configurations.
implementation project(':foo')

// You can, however, keep using variant-specific configurations when
// targeting external dependencies. The following line adds 'app-magic'
// as a dependency to only the 'debug' version of your module.

debugImplementation 'com.example.android:app-magic:12.3'
```

}

here is the link to the full documentation, hope it helps you like it did for me.

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html

Comment: The problem I described above occurred after only upgrading Android Studio. I am still using Gradle 3.3 and the Android Gradle plugin 2.3.3. Having said that, when I did change the Gradle version to 4.1 and the plugin version to 3.0.0 beta and replace `compile` with `implementation` everywhere, the problem still persisted.